# Quarkus/Hiberante relationship between 2 tables

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I try create a simple web application with database. My database has only 2 columns :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Board` (
  `BoardID` Integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` Varchar(255),
  `Position` Integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BoardID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Task` (
  `TaskID` Integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BoardID` Integer NOT NULL,
  `Title` Varchar(255),
  `Description` Varchar (1000),
  PRIMARY KEY (`TaskID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`BoardID`)
  REFERENCES Board(`BoardID`)
);
```

models :

```
@Entity
public class Task extends PanacheEntity {

    @Column(name = "TaskID")
    private Long taskId;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BoardID")
    private Board board;
...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Board extends PanacheEntity{

    @Column(name = "BoardID")
    private Long boardId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Task> task;
...
}
```

My REST method

```
@Path("/hello")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ExampleResource {

    @Inject
    BoardRepository boardRepository;

    @GET
    @Transactional
    public List<Board> getAll() {
        return boardRepository.listAll();
    }
}
```

my code is compiling, but when i call my REST method i receve error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asPJ5.png)

Please help what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What's in your PanacheEntity?

Comment: which database do you use? Also are your pojo annotated with `@Entity`

Comment: i use MySQL. Yes i used annotated @Entity in pojo class.

Comment: @TomStroemer if i good understand PanacheEntity allow use repository like CRUD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code of `PanacheEntity`. From the JavaDoc:

> Represents an entity with a generated ID field {@link #id} of type {@link Long}. If your Hibernate entities extend this class they gain the ID field and auto-generated accessors to all their public fields (unless annotated with {@link Transient}), as well as all the useful methods from {@link PanacheEntityBase}.
>
> If you want a custom ID type or strategy, you can directly extend {@link PanacheEntityBase} instead, and write your own ID field. You will still get auto-generated accessors and
>   all the useful methods.

JavaDoc copied from here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/panache/hibernate-orm-panache/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheEntity.java

Your id-columns don't have the name 'id'. So you should use `PanacheEntityBase` instead and you have to change your entities and add the `@Id` annotation to your id fields:

```
@Entity
public class Task extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TaskID")
    private Long taskId;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BoardID")
    private Board board;
...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Board extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BoardID")
    private Long boardId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Task> task;
...
}
```

If you want to use `PanacheEntity` as your base class you have to change your column names in the database and remove the taskId and boardId from your entities.

Comment: hello would u help me with lazy initialize?When i tried use my Rest method getAll() i received error https://imgur.com/a/04YzGIA

Comment: Please create a new question. Add your complete stacktrace as text and not as image. Please also share the code where you call the method and the relevant parts of your entity.